# MySQL : Alias missing

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

Here's the sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/20113

So, can anyone tell me where did I forgot the alias ?

I checked everywhere, but I can't seem to find where it is wrong.

```
SELECT description 
FROM ForgeRock 
WHERE id=1
UNION 
SELECT 
CONCAT(
version(),
(SELECT (@) FROM (
                  SELECT(@:=0x00),
                        (SELECT @ 
                         FROM ForgeRock 
                         WHERE @ IN     (@:=(CONCAT(@,0x0a,id,0x3a,productName))
                         )
                    )x
 ),version())
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be MySQL?

Comment: your fiddle link is empty

Answer (score 0):

First you forgot a parenthesis. I use [**poorsql**](http://poorsql.com/?inputString=%20%20%20%20DELETE%20t1%20FROM%20jforum_users%20t1%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20EXISTS%0A%20%20%20%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20t1.user_id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FROM%20jforum_users%20t1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20EXISTS%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20t3.*%2C%20t2.*%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FROM%20jforum_users%20t3%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LEFT%20JOIN%20jforum_posts%20t2%20ON%20t3.user_id%20%3D%20t2.user_id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20user_website%20IS%20NOT%20NULL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AND%20t2.user_id%20IS%20NULL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AND%20t1.user_id%20%3D%20t3.user_id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20)&expandCommaLists=true&trailingCommas=false&spaceAfterExpandedComma=false&expandBooleanExpressions=true&expandCaseStatements=true&expandBetweenConditions=true&expandInLists=true&breakJoinOnSections=false&uppercaseKeywords=true&coloring=true&keywordStandardization=true&randomizeColor=false&randomizeLineLengths=false&randomizeKeywordCase=false&preserveComments=false&enableKeywordSubstitution=false&formattingType=standard&indent=%5Ct&spacesPerTab=4&maxLineWidth=999&statementBreaks=2&clauseBreaks=1&language=es&reFormat=true&obfuscate=false) to format your query

If that doesnt solve it let me know

```
SELECT description
FROM ForgeRock
WHERE id = 1

UNION

SELECT CONCAT (
        version()
        ,(
            SELECT (@)
            FROM (
                SELECT (@: = 0x00)
                    ,(
                        SELECT @
                        FROM ForgeRock
                        WHERE @ IN (
                                @: = (
                                    CONCAT (
                                        @
                                        ,0x0A
                                        ,id
                                        ,0x3A
                                        ,productName
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                        ) x
                )
                ,version()
            )
        )
```

Comment: No it doesn't.. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

It's hiding.  You have a few derived tables in there that are bit hard to trace, but every time you do a "SELECT [something] FROM (" you can think of it as a new table that needs an alias.  If you format everything so its a bit easier to read, you can see the subquery for your SELECT (@) FROM statement doesn't have an alias.  As Juan pointed out, you're also missing a closing parenthesis, which I've added below.

```
Select description
  FROM ForgeRock
 Where id = -1
union
select concat(version(),
              (SELECT (@)
                 FROM (SELECT (@ := 0x00) AS T,
                              (SELECT @
                                 FROM ForgeRock
                                WHERE @ IN (@ := (CONCAT(@,
                                                         0x0a,
                                                         id,
                                                         0x3a,
                                                         productName)))) x) imthemissingalias),
              version())
```

Comment: Can you tell me how this derived tables works? first time see so many `@` without a variable name

Comment: Honestly, I haven't seen that either (though I'm primarily Oracle man, so maybe it is common here and I just don't know about it).  It looks like it is converting the product names into a hex form, but I've never seen that done this way, so I'm not sure.  In any case, with the @, when I go back and mess with the SQL Fiddle OP posted, I can add a name to the user defined variable and it returns the same result.  Consequently, I think it just accepts that there is only one variable and doesn't require a name.